# Trying to create a list of lists of a random noise sample in Python 3.X

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, noise

I'm trying to create a list of a certain number of arrays, say 10, where each array is comprised of a number of random numbers between two values in a normal distribution. What I have so far is:

```
noise = abs(np.random.normal(0,0.1,20))
noise1 = []
for i in range(10):
    noise1 = noise.append(range(i,10))
```

Where 'noise' is an array of 20 random positive values between 0 and 0.1. Now I want to create a list of 10 of these arrays with different random numbers each time called 'noise1'. Using this method I get the error 'TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable', meaning the program tries to use the array as a function, but I don't know how to solve the problem. Would really appreciate some help!

Comment: That's not the error this code gives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `numpy.concatenate` or `numpy.append` to append to a numpy array, which is why you are getting your current error.  However, there is a much simpler way to create the list you desire.

```
noise1 = [abs(np.random.normal(0,0.1,20)) for _ in range(10)]
print(np.shape(noise1))
```

Output:

```
(10, 20)
```

Comment: It looks like it worked as I wanted it to, thanks so much for the help.